# Calling Classic ASP Web Service from PHP

Tags: php, web-services

I am wanting to call a Classic ASP web service from PHP.

Here is the service:

```
<%
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.ContentType = "text/xml"

    Set xmldom = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    Set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

Sub Test()
    returnXML = ""
    returnXML = returnXML & "<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP=""urn:schemas-xmlsoap-org:soap.v1"">"
    returnXML = returnXML & "<SOAP:Body>"
    returnXML = returnXML & "<message>"
    returnXML = returnXML & "<theword>Hello</theword>"
    returnXML = returnXML & "</message>"
    returnXML = returnXML & "</SOAP:Body>"
    returnXML = returnXML & "</SOAP:Envelope>"

    Response.Write(returnXML)       
End Sub

    Set xmldom = Nothing
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
%>
```

I want to call this service from PHP in non-WSDL mode. How can I do this? How do I call a specific function within the service?

Here is how I am trying to call the service from PHP:

```
<?php
    $client = new SoapClient(
                null, array(
                        'location' => "http://server/folder/server.asp",
                        'uri'      => "http://test-uri/",
                        'style'    => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
                        'use'      => SOAP_LITERAL,
                        'trace'=>1
                      )
        );

        $result = $client->Test();
        $client->__getLastResponse();
?>
```

Thanks...

Comment: If you have control over the server and client, and they are ASP and PHP, why not just use your own communication API instead of SOAP?  Also, there are libraries out there for classic ASP SOAP web services, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$client->__soapCall()`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php.

I don't believe you can use direct method calls in non-WSDL mode.

**Edit:**

Also, your web service in .asp is not returning any content.  A webservice doesn't actually call a method like Test() on the server.  SOAP is merely a protocol for language-agnostic communication of calls and parameters.  The server needs to actually take the call and apply it to the proper intended method.